# How to run multiple files at the same time?

Tags: node.js, json, discord, discord.js

Okay, so, I have 2 different files at the moment that I have made in Visual Studio Code. I am using `node.js` & `discord.js` , I'm attempting to make a discord bot. When I run the terminal and run "node ." (its how  I usually activate my bot and run its commands, it only activates my `index.js` file and not the other file, which is called `help.js`. I can't seem to make both of these files be run at the same time, its either I activate "index.js" or "help.js" , and future thing is, I'm most likely going to make more different files and want them to run at  the same time. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I didn't really know how to say it. I'm pretty much a beginner in programming and stuff :P

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "run at the same time".  If they're different applications, you start them separately.  If they're pieces of the same app, then you have one master file and you import the other files with either `import` or `require()` depending upon whether you're using the new nodejs module types or the older ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you didn't do a fancypants module structure (aka, assuming you didn't put `exports` in `help.js`), all you have to do is throw this line at the top of `index.js`:

```js
require('./help.js');
```

(assuming `help.js` is in the same folder as `index.js`)

Then keep running `node .` as usual.